# Scrollorama animations wont work in relatively positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the first two pages of a basic Parallax site written using Scrollorama's script, however each 'page' sits in its own div, then each element inside that div is animated. If the containing div is set to absolute positioning, all the inner elements move around just as i have told them too, but then the whole page sits at the left side of the site.

example: http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/Cayton2/

If i center the page by making the containing divs relatively positioned using

```
$('#shop') .css({'position': relative});
```

then the content sites in the center but will not animate.

example: http://bettondesignwork.co.uk/tim/Cayton2-1/

Is there either a way to position the absolute div in the center of the page, or keep all elements animating inside a the relatively positioned divs?

Sorry thats a bit long winded, i hope it makes sence.

Many thanks!